# Relational Database with users and interactions (best relational design)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, design-patterns, relational-database

In a relational database, what would be the best way to implement a relationship where several users each have several interactions with each other?

***Method 1:*** I have an `interactions` table where two of the attributes are `userID1`, `userID2` and the `type` of the interaction. **Problem:** Each time a user wants to access its interactions I will have to look into ALL interactions from ALL users ion the table `interactions` and find, specifically, every instance of interaction with that user. I would guess this is time-consuming and heavy processing.

***Method 2:*** On the other hand, for the `user` table I can create a field which links to an `interactions` table that links with a table of interactions from that user - so each user has an interactions table from himself to other users. **Problem:** To me, it seems faster to search for interactions because every time the user accesses its notifications I just need his ID. However, I would have to create a table for each user which doesn't seem good design to me and can come with many problems.

What is the best (most efficient and best practice) design pattern to use in this case?

Comment: For method 1, if the data looks like `('user1', 'user2', 'like')` does it count as interaction for user1 only or for both users?

Comment: @SalmanA it counts only for 'user1'

Comment: "ALL"??  Sounds like you need suitable INDEXes.  Let's see the SELECTs.

Answer (score 0):

3rd normal form would suggest

Table: Users, PK UserID
Table: Interactions PK InteractionID
Table UserInteractions PK UsrIntID, FK UserID, FK InteractionID

Each Interaction can have 2...N users

Each User can have 0..N Interactions.

Get the User (Interactor), look them up in the the UserInteractions to get a list of their interactions and the associated Users.  Lookup up Users (Interactees) to get user data for other participants